# Which event is fired when switching kb layout in X.org

Tags: c++, c, xorg

I'm new to the X.org programming. I want to build up a small application which reacts on the X keyboard layout switch. I've searched, but didn't find which event is fired when the kb layout is switched. Please, point me to the correct event. Thanks

Comment: What are you doing to switch the keyboard layout? Are you using a GUI client? Or editing a config file? When does the change take effect? These are clues that may help us learn where to look.

Comment: Switching between language layout (en, cs, ...). A GUI client which listens to kb switch (e.g. I have setup both Shifts to switch keyboard layout and this switch generates an event which I want to catch and do some operation). Should be c/c++ code.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Fire up xev and switch keyboard layouts.

Comment: @jthill, using xev won't do. Yes, switching layout via keyboard produces `KeyPress` and `KeyRelease` events with keysym `0xfe08` - `ISO_Next_Group`. However, layout can also be switched though some widget, with a mouse, and then we miss it.

Answer (score 11):

There's the `XkbStateNotify` event type, which is part of the [X Keyboard Extension](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/libX11/specs/XKB/xkblib.html). You can grab layout language from it like this:

```
void x11Events(XEvent* evt)
{
    if(evt->type == xkbEventType) {
        XkbEvent* xkbevt = (XkbEvent*)evt;
        if (xkbevt->any.xkb_type == XkbStateNotify) {
            int lang = xkbevt->state.group;
            // Some code using lang here.
        }
    }
}
```

To get `xkbEventType`, call the `XkbQueryExtension()` function (declared in `XKBlib.h`).

However, `XkbStateNotify` is fired not only on layout change. This is from specification referenced above:

> The changes reported include changes to any aspect of the keyboard
>   state: when a modifier is set or unset, when the current group
>   changes, or when a pointer button is pressed or released.

Because of this, you'll have to save the value of `lang` somewhere, and then, when new event arrives, compare new value of `lang` to the one previously saved.

NB. There's also the `XkbMapNotifyEvent` event, which notifies not about switching layout per se, but about changing keyboard mapping. You might want to look into that one, too.

Comment: Of note to programmers might be a hint how to obtain this event using a modern toolkit such as GTK.

Comment: In GTK, there's usually no need for processing raw `XEvents` (not for detecting layout change, at least), since there're [gdk events](https://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gdkevent.html), which can be used to get current keyboard group, too. Moreover, meddling in X event processing in gtk apps can undermine the toolkit, since it has its own event processing loop. I don't no much about Qt, but I suspect things are similar there.

Comment: That's exactly what I was referring to - the code equivalent to the above, but using the GDK events. It must be possible to access Xkb layout switch event from GTK/GDK, because at least the keyboard indicator applets need to detect the switch.

Comment: The only gdk event I see that can be used to detect keyboard group change is `GdkEventKey`. Even assuming we'll manage to listen to the root window events (since all event handling in gdk/gtk is window/widget-based, and we want all the events, not just the ones for specific window), we'll still only detect layout changes done via keyboard, and miss those done by other means. So, I don't see how it can be done. Not even sure it's possible. I do know how to get to raw `XEvents` from a GTK app, though. I could write it up in my answer, but it feels like too specific a digression.

Comment: GDK actually supports a hook to snoop at events regardless of which widget they belong to: `gdk_event_handler_set`. This is normally taken by GTK, but as long as one remembers to call `gtk_main_do_event`, one can react to the event as necessary. It would be interesting to see how the various Gnome keyboard layout indicators are implemented.

Comment: Hm, both [libgnomekbd](https://git.gnome.org/browse/libgnomekbd/tree/libgnomekbd) (see gkbd-configuration.c:224) and [xfce4-xkb-plugin](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/panel-plugins/xfce4-xkb-plugin) (see panel-plugin/xkb-config.c:112) listen to the "X-state-changed" glib event, which is emitted by [libxklavier](http://sourcecodebrowser.com/libxklavier/5.1/files.html) (see xklavier.c:498). The xklavier library listens to X events (in the `xkl_xkb_process_x_event()` function). So, using libxklavier (and glib) is another possibility to detect layout change (links above provide some examples).

Comment: <code>XkbEvent event;

XkbSelectEvents(display, XkbUseCoreKbd, XkbAllEventsMask, XkbAllEventsMask);

        while (True) {
            XNextEvent(display, &event.core);
            ...
        }</code> I think about something like this. This handles the keyboard switch and CTRL/ALT/Caps Log/... . This is fine for me, but how to setup XkbSelectEvents to handle only keyboard switch? Thanks.

Comment: There's really no way to select only keyboard switch events. There *is*, however, a way around this. Use `XPeekEvent()` instead of `XNextEvent()` to check whether the next event on the queue is a layout switch and only then, if it is, call `XNextEvent()`.